# Paragraphed HTML Output Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my output out as submitted but it is not working. Say, if I submit a two paragraphed post (by pressing enter key to separate them)
it doesn't output that way. It removes the paragraph and display the post as one paragraph.

**Displayed Result:**

`I am trying to get my output out as submitted but it is not working. 
Say, if I submit a two paragraphed post (by pressing enter key to separate them)
it doesn't output that way. It removes the paragraph and display the post as one paragraph.`

**Expected Result:**

`I am trying to get my output out as submitted but it is not working. 
Say, if I submit a two paragraphed post (by pressing enter key to separate them)
it doesn't output that way.`

`It removes the paragraph and display the post as one paragraph.`

**HTML code:**

```
<form method="post" role = "form" class="form-horizontal" name="" action ="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
    <label for = "status" style = "font-style: italic; margin-bottom: 0;">Post something </label>
    <textarea id = 'posttext' rows = '3' maxlength="320" name="postupdate" placeholder="Share ..."></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary onespacedown" name = "update" type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The db is storing `\n` or `\r\n` depending on the OS

Easy solution. Wrap the output with `nl2br()` browsers expect HTML

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/nl2br) function. Wrap your variable in that to get the desired output.

```
nl2br($_POST['posttext']);
```